# Fluid Simulation not working

Tags: eevee-render-engine, fluid-simulation

Recently I updated my Blender and was excited to see the addition of mantaflow. I tried baking a simulation ensuring that the domain, flow, and effector is placed properly in the space with proper settings. I tried baking the simulation and blender processes it.

Once done while playing back the sequence, there is nothing and the domain still stays same without being transparent.

---

It works when the cube size is default and does not work when the shape is a cuboid